# continuous iOS location updates in background

Tags: ios, iphone, location, core-location

I am trying to create a simple iOS app that will continuously track location in the background and notify with high accuracy when the user has entered a specific region (don't want to use region monitoring because it's not accurate or fast enough for what I want).

This app works fine in the foreground but once I go into the background it does not work.

I created a test app to investigate how background location updates work.  I made a simple app that just prints out a message when a location update happens (to the log).

What I see is that in foreground mode the updates happen as expected but when I lock my phone and the app switches to background the location updates happen for about 30 seconds and then stop.  There is no mention in the Apple docs (that I can find) explaining this behavior.

I made sure that I enabled background processing in the info.plist (done in  "capabilities" --> "background modes" --> "location updates")

Here is the code I used to test this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager() 
var counter = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // configure location updates
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 0.1
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("location updated! \(counter)")
    counter = counter + 1
}
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing?  I tried different location accuracy settings (such as BestForNavigation, etc) and no change.

Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to clarify that in order to test location updates in the background the print statement won't work (that only works by printing to the Mac when the app is in the foreground).  To test it  I added some code to send a local notification inside of didUpdateLocations.  When I switched to background this sent me a notification whenever location got updated.  I got notifications for about 30 seconds after switching to background and then they stopped.

Comment: Also, to be clear, I allowed background processing mode for location in the info.plist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add this in your plist :

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

add this

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I already have this setting in my info.plist (mentioned above but near the end).  As a double check I took a look at the raw file and I do see this (as expected):           <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
     <array>
      <string>location</string>
     </array>

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be the answer:
[allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates)

> Apps that want to receive location updates when suspended must include
> the UIBackgroundModes key (with the location value) in their app’s
> Info.plist file and set the value of this property to true.
>
> ...
>
> The
> default value of this property is false.

Are you setting that?

Comment: Yes, this is being set.

Comment: You mention locking the phone. Does the same thing happen if you don't lock your phone, but just go to the home screen to background the app?

Comment: It works fine with phone unlocked.  Only in background does it get suspended.  But adding  "allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates" made it work.

Comment: Oh, I thought you said you were setting that when I mentioned it above. Anyway, glad you got it working.

Comment: I included the correct key setting in info.plist but I missed your mention of allowsBackgroundUpdates (didn't realize they were two different things at first).  I didn't realize till later that you also answered my question.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add these two line to make it working in background mode:

```
locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```